# C# multithreaded server. pass object to main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have very little experience with threading, and I have googled this for hours without figuring this out.

I followed this tutorial:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server

What is the best way to pass an object from the threads that handle client communication to the main thread. I just want to pass simple data such as who is connected and who sent what message.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're going down the "thread per client" route (which despite what the tutorial says, doesn't scale terribly well), why do you want/have a "main thread", and why do you want it interacting with anything relating to separate clients?

Comment: I want a gui on the server side that lists connected clients and what they are doing. What is a better way of solving this than one thread per client?

Comment: Work item queue with a common pool of threads that handle items from the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use simple synchronization, but that would cause contention in the connection threads, so you can use a queue or similar.

For example :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem

You have an example in C# here : http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/deadlocks.shtml